Aren't "never-ending" numbers like PI and root 2 a sign that the present rules that build counting numbers insufficient?
In coordinate system we already assume that the measurements used to define space is:

Divided into equal units
We also assume that a unit in number system (1,2,3,4 etc.) can only be divided into 2 equal parts. But not eg. 3. ( 1/3 = 0.33333333....)
Point 1 also implies that horizontal and vertical distances have got a real-number relationship with diagonal distances. (But numbers like square-root of 2 actually denies that.)

Isn't that the above rules actually cause the unending values of PI and Square root of 2 and similar numbers? Eg. If we had assumed that 1/3 is actually some completed value then PI would have ended somewhere with that assumption? That is, it's all about how you make the base rules and assumptions in number system.
PS: My question comes from some stories on internet where people keep finding the next digit in PI , most probably to see where it might end.

So is 1/3 "never ending"?? Looks short n sweet to me...

I'm asking what is (the OPs) notion of neverending. You're welcome to call that obtuse @JD ☺️

Decimal expansion is a representation of a number. 1/3 is another one. Do not conflate number with its rep.

It makes no sense to say that "a unit can be divided into 2 equal parts but not into 3". 1/2 = 0.5000000.... (with infinitely many zeros) = 0.4999999.... (with infinitely many 9's). As @MauroALLEGRANZA said, numbers are not their representations.

@mudskipper And 1/3 is 0.1₃ ie in base 3

If we like, we can even use base pi, and make every number except multiples of pi and 0 irrational.

I don't understand any of your assumptions, and how they relate to irrational Numbers.

@jd The decimal expansion of every number is infinite. Let 3 = 3.0000000000... , Similarly 0.999999999.... = 1 etc.

@MichaelCarey Don't you mean ...0003.000...? I prefer succ(succ(succ(0))).

@gs I've sometimes explored using the golden ratio Φ as a number base, because of the way its powers combine (without getting far).

@jd preceding decimal zeroes don't mean anything. Note that 0.999... and 1 converge while ...999.0 and 1 diverge

@gs I beg to differ. There are philosophical overtones since preceding 0's make explicit that numbers can get infinitely large, and trailing 0's make explicit that numbers can get infinitely precise. Thus, there are two dimensions of analysis in every real number [quantity] and [precision]. But I was mostly being facetious. ; )

@Vishwas It's a good question as you learn more about numbers. Pi has no last digit, FYI. And ignore all of the down votes. This site can be a tad unsympathetic.


Isn't that the above rules actually cause the unending values of PI and Square root of 2 and similar numbers?

No.
Irrationals like π and √2 continue endlessly without a pattern, because there exists pairs of abstract magnitudes that are incommensurate.
Numbers mark definite quantitative relationships, and in the case of √2 for instance, there is no ratio between the side and diagonal of a square.
That is, the side and diagonal (of a square) are incommensurate: there is no unit (smallest length) that will fit into both lengths (side and diagonal) an integer number of times.
No definition created this scenario: it was a discovery of the Ancient Greeks, usually attributed to the Pythagoreans.

Natural numbers (integers) are usually represented as sequences of digits. It's important to keep in mind that such a representation is just a convenient shorthand for writing a sum

123 = 3⋆100 + 2⋆101 + 1⋆102

So, we only write the coefficients using 10 as positional base.
This kind of representation gets a "natural" extension for rational numbers, fractions based on natural numbers.

1/2 = 0.5 = 0⋆100 + 5⋆10-1

Using this representation for fractions leads to two (related) problems. One is that some fractions can not be written as a finite sum. The other is that every fraction can be represented as two apparently different sums:

1/7 = 0.142857142857142857...
1/2 = 0.5 = 0.499999...

The first problem means there is no solution to the equation 1/7 = ∑ ai⋆10-i such that the right-hand side only has a finite number of integer coefficients. To deal with that, and justify the representation, we need the concept of mathematical limit. Given a clear concept of limit, we can then also prove that 0.5 and 0.49999... refer to the same number.
Given the concept of limit, we can then also extend the number system to real numbers - numbers that include all rationals, but also numbers like square root of 2 which can not be written as rational, and which therefore necessarily have an infinite decimal expansion in any (natural number) base.
Note that whether or not a rational number can only be written as an infinite sum depends on the chosen base. In base 10 we have that 1/3 is represented as 0.3333.... but in base 3 the same number is represented as 0.1; in a decimal system 1/5 is 0.2 but in binary notation it is 0.001100110011... (infinitely repeating). So, the fact that some numbers require an infinite expansion by itself does not signify there are any "insufficiencies" with the theory of numbers (apart from the fact that you do need a good concept of limit).
The issue of representation/notation does become very relevant, of course, when dealing with software: rational numbers and reals will usually be represented as floating point numbers in binary, which implies there can be no exact representation of certain numbers (such as 0.2) -- unless special software is used (representing the number as pair of integers in this case).

+1 "Given a clear concept of limit, we can then also prove that 0.5 and 0.49999... refer to the same number." Simpler is the algebraic strategy 10x - x : x = 0.nnnn....

@JD - I think the subtraction (and multiplication) is only justified since x = 0.499999.... is well-defined (as a convergent sum). Without the proof of convergence, x itself doesn't seem meaningful as representation of a number and the subtraction might be invalid (or lead to absurdities). So, to informally suggest the identity, the algebraic way is simpler, but to really prove it, I think, you need limits.

@JD and mudskipper. This video https://youtu.be/MJee0UdWRcQ shows graph for f(x) = 1/x. Then f(x) = 1/2 = 0.5 for x = 2.  But f(x) < 0.5 for x > 2. To me this means 0.49999... is always less than 0.5 when we map numbers to the real number line.

@SystemTheory Thanks. It's always fascinating to think of non-terminating decimals as graphically asymptotic.

You ask:

Isn't that the above rules actually cause the unending values of PI and Square root of 2 and similar numbers? Eg. If we had assumed that 1/3 is actually some completed value then PI would have ended somewhere with that assumption?

"Never-ending" numbers are often called non-terminating, non-repeating decimals. This notion that we have a number, but it goes on forever creates some cognitive dissonance since numbers like the counting, naturals, and integers are composed of sets of symbols that in their simplest expression have representations that do not indicate they go on forever. (Though every integer can be expressed as z.000...) Thus, non-repeating decimals invoke the notions of randomness, algorithms and infinity.
So, yes, there are two fundamentally different classes of numbers based on their typical representations. When you talk about completed, we can separate some numbers into one set which are not defined by an algorithm as individual numbers (actually, the naturals are defined often in terms of Peano axioms (PA). This is in contrast to numbers whose decimal representation is algorithmic (like 1/9 being 0.111... or Pi).
With non-repeating decimals, philosophy enters when one starts thinking about what it means to be a number given that some people think infinity is actual and others think it is potential. In some sense, for instance, we can say Pi IS the algorithm by which we define it, or we can also say Pi is the decimal representation. In the first sense, Pi is actual because we might say that the algorithm provides us all we need to know what Pi means. In the second sense, Pi constantly seems potential because no matter how many digits we calculate, we can always find one more.
Which is the "right" way? Well the answer depends on what you mean by number, and is at the heart of the philosophy of mathematics. For a neo-Platonic thinker, in some sense, Pi might have an essence. For others, Pi is an experiment since we can't know a priori all of it's decimal values. And engineers will simply say "Who cares. I have to round off the value anyway!"
So, when you ask:

Aren't "never-ending" numbers like PI and root 2 a sign that the present rules that build counting numbers insufficient?

Yes. PA does NOT produce irrationals or non-repeating decimals by itself. Thus, we have to have other systems or mathematical objects that are more complicated. A good example of that is the notion of a field in abstract algebra. As the structures get more complicated, the definition of number does too! Just consider that the inverse operation of a square creates the imaginary numbers, and then those are used to build complex numbers, and those are use to build quarternions. Thus, whatever numbers are, it is certainly a very rich discussion.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal

A repeating decimal or recurring decimal is a decimal representation of a number whose digits are eventually periodic (that is, after some place, the same sequence of digits is repeated forever); if this sequence consists only of zeros (that is if there is only a finite number of nonzero digits), the decimal is said to be terminating, and is not considered as repeating.


Any number that cannot be expressed as a ratio of two integers is said to be irrational. Their decimal representation neither terminates nor infinitely repeats, but extends forever without repetition. (pi, sqrt(2)).


Every rational number is either a terminating or repeating decimal
For any given divisor, only finitely many different remainders can occur. In the example above, the 74 possible remainders are 0, 1, 2, ..., 73. If at any point in the division the remainder is 0, the expansion terminates at that point. Then the length of the repetend, also called "period", is defined to be 0.  If 0 never occurs as a remainder, then the division process continues forever, and eventually, a remainder must occur that has occurred before. The next step in the division will yield the same new digit in the quotient, and the same new remainder, as the previous time the remainder was the same. Therefore, the following division will repeat the same results. The repeating sequence of digits is called "repetend" which has a certain length greater than 0, also called "period".[5]
In base 10, a fraction has a repeating decimal if and only if in lowest terms, its denominator has any prime factors besides 2 or 5, or in other words, cannot be expressed as 2^m *5^n, where m and n are non-negative integers.

